# Erro: expected { ao criar uma classe

Tags: java, classes, sintaxe

Eu escrevi o código abaixo, mas ele está me dando o erro

> expected {

depois da declaração da minha classe

```
public class book(string title, string text){
    string _title = title;
    string _text = text;

    void NewTitle (book livro, string newtitle){
    livro._title = newtitle;
    }

    string BookTitle (book livro){
    return livro._title;
    }

    string BookText (book livro){
    return livro._text; 
   }

    int BookLength (book livro){
    return (livro._title.length + livro._text.length);
   }

    boolean samebook(book livro1, book livro2){
        return (livro1._title == livro2._title && livro1._text == livro2._text);
   }

}
```

Comment: Errou de stackoverflow é?

Comment: I don't understand what could be wrong to give an { expected error after the public class book.

Comment: Sugestão, se você fala português, escreva em português. Caso contrário, you should ask it in stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Oh, nem reparei! Voce poderia me ajudar então? Agradecido!

Comment: Boa noite André e qual é o erro que aparece no Console?

Comment: Error: Expected { onde tem o ( aseguir a class book.

Comment: André é melhor traduzir a pergunta e colocar o erro todo descrito no console do java junto a edição, pois se não a pergunta será fechada e após você editar, pode levar um tempo pra reabrir, note que fechar uma pergunta não tem nada demais, é apenas pra evitar respostas enquanto a pergunta não segue o minimo de qualidade.

Comment: Você colocou parênteses depois do nome da classe (como se estivesse escrevendo um construtor). Retire os parênteses. Ainda não vai compilar, pois você está tentando atribuir os campos a partir dos parâmetros do "construtor". Pare de atribui-los (só declare, ou atribua explicitamente a `null`). Então vai compilar. Por fim, pode criar um construtor que atribua esses campos a partir dos parâmetros. P.S. Se você traduzir a pergunta, eu posto isso como resposta (não o faço agora senão tomo *downvote*.. :P)

Comment: P.S. Isso é Java mesmo, ou é C#? Se é Java, tem também o problema da string com letra minúscula (é `String`). E em todo caso, você não precisa passar a própria instância como parâmetro (como em Python, por exemplo), basta omiti-lo e usar `this` para se referir ao objeto atual (ou, no caso dos campos, só referi-lo pelo nome - ao contrário de JavaScript por exemplo, que exige o uso do `this`).

Comment: Se é `Java` voce deve usar String e não string.

Comment: Não entendi pra que estes negativos. Eles não sabe como fazer. Isto não significa que a pergunta é ruim. Se foi porque estava em inglês, pior ainda.

Comment: @bigown Acho que os votos negativos foram antes da edição, ou não? Entretanto pode ter sido que o AP não traduziu a pergunta e quem acabou traduzindo foi outro colega, talvez alguém ache que o AP não mostrou o minimo de empenho. No entanto vou deixar o meu +1 pra apoiar :)

Comment: Foram, mas não se justifica. Isso falha de entendimento do site só. Se fizeram isto, puniram o conteúdo querendo punir a pessoa, que não é nosso objetivo.

Comment: @AndréSoares Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

O erro mais óbvio que está fazendo é colocar uma lista de parâmetros em uma classe. Classe não é método. Java não possui o recurso de *primary constructor* (existe em [Kotlin](http://kotlinlang.org/) e há [proposta para isto em C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) que é mais ou menos o que você está tentando fazer, embora duvido que fosse a intenção.

Na verdade você vai ter que criar um construtor para fazer o que deseja. Parece que você fundiu a sintaxe da classe com a do construtor. Então tem que criar as variáveis de instância para serem usadas por estes métodos.

Mas há outros erros. O tipo de texto em Java é `String` e não pode ser escrito em minúsculo. Para saber o tamanho do texto tem que chama o método `length()`. Não é uma propriedade, como é em outras linguagens.

`samebook` (nome ruim) provavelmente deveria ser `static`.

Não é comum em Java se usar o `_` em nomes de variáveis. Os métodos costuma ser minúsculo. Alguns deste métodos são chamados de *getters* e *stters*. Não use o nome da classe no nome do método a não ser que tenha um motivo muito bom para isto, isto é redundante. Exemplo do que seria melhor: `setTitle()`, `getTitle()`, `getText()` e `length()`. E o nome da classe costuma ser usado em maiúsculo. Não é erro, claro.

Tem algumas outras coisas que em código real pode não ser bem o que deveria fazer, mas me parece um exercício e isto não influencia. Eu nem sei quais são os requisitos.

Então ficaria assim:

```
class Book {
    private String _title;
    private String _text;

    Book(String title, String text) {
        _title = title;
        _text = text;
    }
    void NewTitle(Book livro, String newtitle) {
        livro._title = newtitle;
    }

    String BookTitle(Book livro) {
        return livro._title;
    }

    String BookText(Book livro) {
        return livro._text; 
    }

    int BookLength(Book livro) {
        return (livro._title.length() + livro._text.length());
    }

    boolean samebook(Book livro1, Book livro2){
        return (livro1._title == livro2._title && livro1._text == livro2._text);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Book.java).